# urlretrieve generates an http error 404 after a couple of downloads

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to download some images this way:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url_ds3_part1 = 'https://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com'

url_ds3 = {
"daggers":"https://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Daggers",
"straight_swords":"https://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Straight+Swords",
"great_swords":"https://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Greatswords",
"ultra_great_swords":"https://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Ultra+Greatswords",
"curved_swords":"https://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Curved+Swords",
"katanas":"https://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Katanas",
"curved_great_swords":"https://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Curved+Greatswords",
"piercing_swords":"https://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Piercing+Swords"
}

for url in url_ds3.values():
    content = requests.get(url).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml') 
    image_tags = soup.findAll('img')
    [urllib.request.urlretrieve(url_ds3_part1+str(image_tag.get('src')), str('images_swords')+str(image_tag.get('src'))) for image_tag in image_tags if (('forum' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)
                                                                                                                                                     & (('None' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)
                                                                                                                                                     & (('avatar' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)
                                                                                                                                                     & (('Damage' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)  
                                                                                                                                                     & (('Resist' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)
                                                                                                                                                     & (('STR' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)  
                                                                                                                                                     & (('DEX' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)  
                                                                                                                                                     & (('INT' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)  
                                                                                                                                                     & (('FTH' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)   
                                                                                                                                                     & (('attack' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)    
                                                                                                                                                     & (('normal' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)    
    ]
```

You can just copy/paste the code to reproduce the error HHTP 404 Error.
I'm kinda new to this (first time I did scraping) but I suspect he struggles with duplicates or something, kinda struggle decomposing this problem ?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

EDIT: Forgot to add url_ds3_part1
EDIT2: This should give you an idea of the images I'm trying to retrieve:

```
for url in url_ds3.values():
    content = requests.get(url).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml') 
    image_tags = soup.findAll('img')
    [print(url_ds3_part1+str(image_tag.get('src'))) for image_tag in image_tags if (('forum' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)
                                                                                 & (('None' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)
                                                                                 & (('avatar' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)                   
                                                                                 & (('Damage' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)  
                                                                                 & (('Resist' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)
                                                                                 & (('STR' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)  
                                                                                 & (('DEX' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)  
                                                                                 & (('INT' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)  
                                                                                 & (('FTH' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)   
                                                                                 & (('attack' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)    
                                                                                 & (('normal' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)    
    ]
```

EDIT 3 :
Temporarely bypassed the issue with try

```
for url in url_ds3.values():
    content = requests.get(url).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml') 
    image_tags = soup.findAll('img')
    try:
        [urllib.request.urlretrieve(url_ds3_part1+str(image_tag.get('src')), str('images_swords')+str(image_tag.get('src'))) for image_tag in image_tags if (('forum' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)
                                                                                                                                                          & (('None' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)
                                                                                                                                                          & (('avatar' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)
                                                                                                                                                          & (('Damage' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)  
                                                                                                                                                          & (('Resist' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)
                                                                                                                                                          & (('STR' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)  
                                                                                                                                                          & (('DEX' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)  
                                                                                                                                                          & (('INT' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)  
                                                                                                                                                          & (('FTH' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)   
                                                                                                                                                          & (('attack' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)    
                                                                                                                                                          & (('normal' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)    
        ] 
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: What images is the script supposed to get? Just the icons found in column `"Name & Icon"`?

Comment: I'm sorry I left some confusion in the code as I forgot to define my variable url_ds3_part1 , now if you execute everything yeah you should get the icons but at one point it will stop retreiving everything and will make the 404 error message

Answer (score 1):

Running your code it seems that some URLs are absolute (they start with `https://`) and some are not. You need to check for that:

```
import requests
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_ds3 = {
"daggers":"https://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Daggers",
"straight_swords":"https://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Straight+Swords",
"great_swords":"https://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Greatswords",
"ultra_great_swords":"https://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Ultra+Greatswords",
"curved_swords":"https://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Curved+Swords",
"katanas":"https://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Katanas",
"curved_great_swords":"https://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Curved+Greatswords",
"piercing_swords":"https://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Piercing+Swords"
}


url_ds3_part1 = 'https://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com'

for url in url_ds3.values():
    print(url)

    content = requests.get(url).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml') 
    image_tags = soup.findAll('img')

    for image_tag in image_tags:
        if ( (('forum' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)
             & (('None' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)
             & (('avatar' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)
             & (('Damage' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)  
             & (('Resist' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)
             & (('STR' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)  
             & (('DEX' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)  
             & (('INT' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)  
             & (('FTH' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)   
             & (('attack' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False)    
             & (('normal' in str(image_tag.get('src'))) == False) ):

            if image_tag.get('src').startswith('http'):
                u = image_tag['src']
            else:
                u = url_ds3_part1 + image_tag['src']

            urllib.request.urlretrieve(u, 'images_swords' + image_tag['src'].replace(url_ds3_part1, ''))
```